# Is it feasible to call angular's page from wordpress website?

Tags: javascript

I have a static website on WordPress and there are 2 to 3 pages which has dynamic content and which does requires user authentication. So can I build these pages on angular side and call these pages from word-press ?
I found this article
https://laternastudio.com/blog/including-an-angular-7-app-inside-wordpress-laravel-or-any-php-page/
But I am using Elementor Plugin, in which how can I incorporate my Angular code ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after searching for so many hours.

1. In your functions.php file add the java-scripts file which you have got after ng build.
2. Before doing `ng build` , in your angular.json file set `"outputhasing": "none"`
3. After building , inside the dist folder in the index.html file change the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`
4. Now copy the dist folder into the particular location on server. I am using Apache 2.4.0
5. Now in alias.conf file inside `/etc/apache2/mods-available/` folder add the Alias as follows:  `Alias pathNameOnURL "pathOfDirectory"`  example: Alias /icons "/var/www/websitePages/"
6. restart the apache server , and try to access this path you'll get your page running.

[Referred from](https://www.panda-os.com/blog/2014/01/integrating-angularjs-wordpress/)